# Is gzip compression efficient for repetitive text content? Multiple terms that show up multiple times in the string that is being compressed

Tags: html, http, gzip

I have this products-like page that I'm using SSR with NextJS. Users can search, filter, pagination, etc.

It's not a huge amount of items, so I decided to send them all as `props` to the page, doing all that functionality on client-side only. Raw `props` data is now roughly ~350kb and gzipped is ~75kb.

I think this is worth it, because I can save a lot on database reads, and I didn't have to setup any search/cache server to implement the searching/filtering functionality. It's all done on the client, becuase it has all the items in-memory.

The `product` object has a shape similar to this:

```
{
  longPropertyName: value,
  stringEnum: 'LONG_STRING_VALUE'
}
```

What I could do to optmize data traffic would be to shorten property names, and refactor string enums into numeric enums, so it would be:

```
{
  shortProp: value,
  numericEnum: 1
}
```

This for sure would reduce the uncompressed data size from ~350kb to maybe ~250kb.

But I'm not sure if it's worth doing it, because I think the `gzipped` size would remain very much the same, because I'm assuming the `gzip` compression is very good in compressing repetitive text content, like property names and string enum values that show up multiple times in the data.

Would I get a reduction on the `gzip` size by the same factor? Or will it be just the same value?

Comment: How about you test it? It's the best way to get the answer, and seriously, it's easy to do.

Comment: Sure, but maybe (probably) someone here has previous experience with this or very solid knowledge about how gzip compression works. Anyway, I think I'll do at least the `enum` refactor and I'll let you know. Thanks

Comment: You don't have to refactor anything to test it. Download the raw content, gzip it, then replace those strings in raw content it, gzip it again, compare.

Comment: Also, gzip will efficiently compress repetitive content. So, it is likely that both compressed versions won't differ much.

Comment: I can gzip using `gzip` from the terminal, right? I was not aware of that. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there also gui gzip clients, like a lot of them.

Comment: Could you recommend me one?

Comment: Not really, I'm a command line guy. :)

Comment: Just tested it! I won't be spending a lot of time in that optimization. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gzip will find repeated strings that are no farther than 32K bytes from each other. It will encode up to 258 bytes of match at a time as a very compact length and distance. That is well suited to your application, whether or not you tokenize the information. Tokenization will improve the compression, both by making the matches shorter, permitting more text per match, but also by supporting more distant matches by bringing what was further away into that 32K.

You can also try more modern compressors such as zstd or lzma2 (xz), which support much farther distances and longer matches.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it locally and while I was able to remove `20kb` from uncompressed data by replacing the string enums with numeric enums, the change in the compressed data was only `1.1kb`.

It means that `gzip` is already doing 95% of the work for me.

Note: I tested the `gzip` size with:

```
gzip -c filename.min.js | wc -c
```

---

I ended up writing a minification/expand logic for those objects. I'm doing SSR, so I minify on the server, and expand on the client. That reduced the uncompressed props data from `350kb` to `168kb` and the final compressed page size from `75kb` to `45kb`.

Simple logic like:

On server:

```
{ longProp: value } => { a: value }
{ stringEnum: STRING_VALUE => { b: 5 }
```

On client:

```
{ a: value } => { longProp: value }
{ b: 5 } => { stringEnum: STRING_VALUE
```

Comment: I agree, it is probably not worth it to complicate logic only to get 5% improvement.

Comment: @freakish I aded a simple minification logic that really did the trick. Thanks again for you help!